# What http methods are absolutely required for a web server?

Tags: http, webserver

What is the bare minimum of the http protocol that every webserver must implement? In other words, what part of the http is absolutely necessary to deliver webpages to normal web browsers?

Comment: See [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) to get an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [RFC 2616 Section 5.1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5):

> The methods GET and HEAD MUST be supported by all general-purpose servers. All other methods are OPTIONAL; however, if the above methods are implemented, they MUST be implemented with the same semantics as those specified in section 9.